# How to implement parent object attributes (props & values) for children objects during JAXB XML unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have XML configuration that I must unmarshal with JAXB and then use this objects in java code. I have one parent object "tags" and two child tags "innerTag". All tags have attributes. Input configuration is:

```
...
<tags attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">
<innerTag attribute3="value3"/> 
<innerTag attribute4="value4"/>
</tags>
...
```

My task is implementation of attribute1 and attribute2 for innerTags after unmarshaling. It must be unmarshal like such xml:

```
...
<tags>
<innerTag attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" attribute3="value3"/> 
<innerTag attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" attribute4="value4"/>
</tags>
...
```

I create the classes that will represent the objects after parsing XML:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Tags {
private ArrayList<InnerTag> innerTags = new ArrayList<>();
private String attribute1;
private String attribute2;
...
@XmlElement(name = "innerTag")
@XmlElementWrapper(name="tags")
public ArrayList<InnerTag> getInnerTags(){
    return innerTags;
   }
...
@XmlAttribute
public String getAttribute1(){
    return attribute1;
   }

@XmlAttribute
public String getAttribute2(){
    return attribute2;
   }
...
}
```

And the InnerTag class:

```
@XmlRootElement
class InnerTag {
private String attribute1;
private String attribute2;
private String attribute3;
private String attribute4;
...
@XmlAttribute
public String getAttribute1(){
    return attribute1;
   }

@XmlAttribute
public String getAttribute2(){
    return attribute2;
   }
...
@XmlAttribute
public String getAttribute3(){
    return attribute3;
   }

@XmlAttribute
public String getAttribute4(){
    return attribute4;
   }
}
```

I have no idea how to implement the attributes and values of parent attribute for children... I have not found such JAXB derective that let me do such implementation of attributes. Help, please to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this,

unmarshal the `Tags` object firstly

```
File file = new File("XMLFile.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tags.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Tags tags = (Tags) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

then, attribute's (attribute1 and attribute2) values of `tags` set to the `InnerTag`

```
for (int i = 0; i < tags.getInnerTags().size(); i++) {
    tags.getInnerTags().get(i).setAttribute1(tags.getAttribute1());
    tags.getInnerTags().get(i).setAttribute2(tags.getAttribute2());
}
```